# Passing rendered string to exec() doesn't escape ` " `

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, nunjucks

I have a nunjucks template. When I render it, I get the following string =>

```
something something '{"firstName": "john", "lastName": "doe", "age": 12}'
```

But when i pass it to [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) it's treated as =>

```
something something '{firstName: john, lastName: doe, age: 12}'
```

Is there a way to avoid that?

Sample code =>

```
function getCommand(){
    // render template
    return renderedString;
}

const command = getCommand();
exec(command);
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if the string is generated by nunjucks or not. Before passing something to `exec`, *you* have the responsibility to escape it appropriately.

Comment: Also consider using [`spawn` with its arguments array](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) instead of `exec` if you want to launch a particular process